# How hibernate alias works

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am working with hibernate since 2 years but I suddenly get curious about one thing that whenever I write some hql in hibernate it will parse query and will add some alias like 'select item_name as item_90_0' when we are not providing any alias. I tried to search a lot that how this alias is provided with specific number but I didn't get proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you didn't find anything (and why you didn't care for 2 years) is because it is completely irrelevant (as long as it works properly). So nobody is writing about this. If you want the actual nitty gritty details, you should step through the source code, but I think I can give a general idea of what is going on:

Hibernate takes an abstract instruction for a query (HQL, Criteria Api or a message call like Session.get) and converts it into a sql statement. Since such a sql statement often contains joins, including self-joins column and table names might not be unique. Therefore hibernate creates aliases for tables and columns.

For this it seems to take a base name, append and underscore and numbers. The base name is normally the simple name of the column or table in question

Of course this might create conflicts when your tables or columns happens to be named with such a pattern. For example you might have a table t and a table t_1 which might collide with the alias that hibernate generates.

To avoid this Hibernate doesn't seem to use the full name, but only the part until the first underscore. And I'm sure they have to do more tricks to avoid other problems with strange names.