# how to make hibernate stop using the wierd aliases when generating queries?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, logging

right now i have this kind of aliased queries :

`select r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roles r1_0 where r1_0.name=?`

& i want it to be like this, mainly to improve readability of the queries, i cannot deal with those aliases ..

`select roles.id,roles.name from roles where roles.name=?`

this is a snippet of what the `Role` entity looks like :

```
@Entity(name = "roles")
@Table(name = "roles")
@Data
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private ERole name;
    
    public Role() {
        
    };
    
    public Role(@NonNull ERole role) {
        this.name = role;
    };

}
```

so as you can see i set the table name in `@Table` annotation and i want hibernate to "role" and not nay other generated alias.

### Chat GPT :

i used Chat GPT and it proposed to add this to application.properties :

```
hibernate.use_alias_for_entity_reference = false
```

that didn't not work, and i couldn't even find the property `use_alias_for_entity_reference` in Hibernate docs ( i use v6.1 )

Comment: `@Table` doesn't change aliases

Comment: i didn't say it does @Jens

Comment: And why you explicitly told us that you use the annotation

Comment: As I know there is no way to control alias generation

Comment: @Jens i mentioned the annotation to point out that i want Hibernate to use whatever name i mentioned in @Table(name="roles) and not some alternative alias.

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364609/how-hibernate-alias-works